# VB.Net XMLdocument memory management

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, linq-to-xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

```
Dim docu As New XmlDocument()
docu.load("C:\bigfile.xml")

Dim tempNode As XmlNode
tempNode = docu.SelectSingleNode("/header/type")

someArray(someIndex) = tempNode.innerText

...do something more...
```

I am using `XmlDocument()` to load a huge `XML` document (100~300MB)

When I open the document and read it as `string`, my application uses about *900MB* of RAM.
I wonder why it happens and how can I prevent it ?

Note that : even, the `XmlDocument` does not have `Dispose()` to remove allocated things.
Although I need the whole string of the huge XML file in later part of the app, the `/header/type.innerText` is only a single word

---

More of source :

```
Private Sub setInfo(ByVal notePath As String)

        Dim _NOTE As XDocument

        _NOTE = XDocument.Load(notePath)

        If (From node In _NOTE...<title> Select node).Value = "" Then
            lvlist.Items.Add("No Title")
        Else
            lvlist.Items.Add((From node In _NOTE...<title> Select node).Value)
        End If

        lvlist.Items(lvlist.Items.Count - 1).SubItems.Add((From node In _NOTE...<group> Select node).Count)


End Sub
```

It reads XML document, counts  tags and retrieves  string value. That's all.
After having those values, _NOTE (XDocument) is of no use at that time.

Comment: Did you try using XDocument instead?

Comment: @Neolisk Can XDocument free up the memory when its work is done?

Comment: Any .NET object is supposed to do this by default, just make sure you control the variable scope - it directly impacts the lifetime of your object, and as a result - your memory consumption. My hope was that XDocument may be consuming less memory than XmlDocument, because XDocument is relatively new to .NET (hoping that newer is better in this case).

Comment: I've tried "(From node In xdocu...<type> Select node).Value" thing and it successfully gives the right data, while no memory consumption improvement... I think this is because both XDocument and XMLDocument read the whole file at once then load in the memory.

Comment: Yes, they both load the whole thing into memory. Can you show more of your code? So we could get the scope of your `document` variable (whether it's XmlDocument or XDocument), to estimate its life time.

Comment: @Neolisk I wrote more code. Thanks!

Comment: Interesting... so you are saying that even though `_NOTE` is declared inside the `Sub`, .NET does not free memory upon finishing execution of this `Sub` (give several seconds to allow garbage collection to kick in)?

Comment: As suggested [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/2026a448-0dae-489c-9b33-954fad578c92/dispose-xdocument?forum=csharpgeneral), `When the reference goes out of scope and is not hold anymore, the GC will take over and clean/compact managed memory as needed.` How much memory does your PC have? Maybe you have enough, and that's why GC is not kicking?

Comment: Also [try putting XmlDocument inside a Using statement](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/176972-xmldocument-load-method-not-releasing-memory) - see if it helps. This one below is unlikely to be relevant to your question, but I'll leave it here for future visitors. [.NET Memory not freeing up even after exiting the function (C#)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5847146/net-memory-not-freeing-up-even-after-exiting-the-function).

Comment: @Neolisk Yes, even though the _NOTE is only used in the Sub, no apparent cleaning up is proceeded. My PC has 8GB of RAM memory, this might be the reason, but I have to manage the memory problem because loading 300MB XML takes about 2~4 times larger memory.

Comment: plus, Using-End Using statement won't work because XMLDocument or XDocument itself doesn't have IDispose(). Syntax error occured. Thanks for concerning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will probably solve your need. From MSDN:

> Represents a reader that provides fast, **noncached**, forward-only access to XML data.

Comment: Good answer, however, it's worth mentioning that, though much less efficient, if you really want to use `XmlDocument`, you could just set your `XmlDocument` variable to `Nothing` once you're done reading the desired element value, then you can force a garbage collection by calling `GC.Collect`.  That will cause it to immediately free up that memory that was used up by the `XmlDocument` object.  Using `XmlReader` would be preferrable, though, if the file really is that big and you really only need one element value.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: Thank you, Steven. Your comment deserves to be promoted to an answer. :)

Comment: @StevenDoggart Actually, I've tried that. I ended the code with setting docu=Nothing and GC.collect(). However, it doesn't free up the memory... Is XMLReader far different from XMLDocument? I mean, can XMLReader retrieve NODES and select single NODE and so on? thanks!

Comment: @klados: See [How to: Parse XML with XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx). Short answer - there is no 1-to-1 conversion approach. The benefits - you will have greater control with XmlReader, thus avoiding unnecessary reads or memory consumption. Convenience is usually the opposite of control. Pick one.

Comment: @Neolisk then if I want to retrieve a <DESCRIPTION> tag in the specific <GROUP> tags which is more than 1000, should I re-open the XML file, read it from the very first and find it whenever I want to get <DESCRIPTION>?

Comment: @klados: Pretty much, yes. Read from top to bottom, pick anything of interest. Save that for further processing.

Comment: I am converting XMLDocument to XMLReader. It's quite bothersome and not directive while apparently effective to memory management.

Answer (score 0):

Right, `XmlDocument` does not have a `Dispose` method. It is put into memory. It does follow an object life cycle. So if you create the object in a `Function` and return the string you want then it will free itself as it losses scope from the `Function`.